# Magento 2 : Use aftersave and beforesave method

Tags: magento2, save

I want to add `aftersave` and `beforesave` method of Magento 2 in my model.

**How can I do this and which model I have to called ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can used `_beforeSave` and `_afterSave` in your ResourceModel

```
<?php
    namespace Spacename\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel;
    class Test extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb  {

        protected function _beforeSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
        {
      // do your logic here

        }

       protected function _afterSave(\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $object)
        {  
          //do your logic here
        }



    }
```

Comment: If I put logic to save data in _aftersave() function then what will be the use of $object ? I means, Is it compulsory to use $object or save in $object in my logic  ?   (for ex. $object->setName(''Test")->save(); or $mymodel->setName("Test")->save()       )

Comment: `$object->getData('identifier')`

Comment: Sorry.But what do you mean by "identifier" and is it not possible to use in Namespace/Modulname/Model/Test.php ?

Comment: this is your field name `identifier` change as your field name

Comment: ok and as I asked  is it not possible to use in Namespace/Modulname/Model/Test.php ?  If i extend this Test.php file with Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel . Then   ?

Comment: i am following the `cms` module they are doing it in resourceModel. so you have to do in resourceModel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use tag  to rewrite the model you want

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! The best answers include a bit of an example, maybe some code, to show how it's done.